# The cross hatched patterns in Altium viewer

Tags: pcb, altium

I was checking the PCB design of [XIAO RP2040](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/XIAO-RP2040/).

In the online viewer (Altium viewer), I noticed there were some cross hatched area on the top layer, which I believe it's not copper.
As I’m a rookie and have no experience about Altium Designer, just wondering what are these areas.

Thanks.
[image: The cross hatched are in the top layer of PCB]

Comment: Could be keepout or device layer. Just check the layer name.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the red cross hatched area seems to be marking the component package on the top layer.